# truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: ) returning nonZero remainder even if number is completely divisible

Tags: swift4, ios12

I am trying to get remainder using swift's `truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:)` method.
But I am getting a non zero remainder even if value I am using is completely divisible by deviser. I have tried number of solutions available here but none worked.

P.S. values I am using are **Double** (Tried Float also).

Here is my code.

```
    let price = 0.5
    let tick = 0.05
    let remainder = price.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: tick)
    if remainder != 0 {
      return "Price should be in multiple of tick"
    }
```

I am getting `0.049999999999999975` as remainder which is clearly not the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual (see https://floating-point-gui.de), this is caused by the way numbers are stored in a computer.

According to the docs, this is what we expect

```
let price = //
let tick = //
let r = price.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: tick)
let q = (price/tick).rounded(.towardZero)
tick*q+r == price // should be true
```

In the case where it looks to your eye as if `tick` evenly divides `price`, everything depends on the inner storage system. For example, if `price` is `0.4` and `tick` is `0.04`, then `r` is vanishingly close to zero (as you expect) and the last statement is true.

But when `price` is `0.5` and `tick` is `0.05`, there is a tiny discrepancy due to the way the numbers are stored, and we end up with this odd situation where `r`, instead of being vanishingly close to zero, is vanishing close to `tick`! And of course the last statement is then false.

You'll just have to compensate in your code. Clearly the remainder cannot be the divisor, so if the remainder *is* vanishingly close to the divisor (within some epsilon), you'll just have to disregard it and *call* it zero.

You could file a bug on this but I doubt that much can be done about it.

---

Okay, I put in a query about this and got back that it behaves as intended, as I suspected. The reply (from [Stephen Canon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142434/stephen-canon)) was:

> That's the correct behavior. 0.05 is a Double with the value 0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125. Dividing 0.5 by that value in exact arithmetic gives 9 with a remainder of 0.04999999999999997501998194593397784046828746795654296875, which is exactly the result you're seeing.
>
> The only rounding error that occurs in your example is in the division price/tick, which rounds up to 10 before your `.rounded(.towardZero)` has a chance to take effect. We'll add an API to let you do something like `price.divided(by: tick, rounding: .towardZero)` at some point, which will eliminate this rounding, but the behavior of `truncatingRemainder` is precisely as intended.
>
> You really want to have either a decimal type (also on the list of things to do) or to scale the problem by a power of ten so that your divisor become exact:

```
    1> let price = 50.0
      price: Double = 50
    2> let tick = 5.0
      tick: Double = 5
    3> let r = price.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: tick)
      r: Double = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for reflecting the answer here, Matt!

Comment: @StephenCanon I'll put in a reference to you! Thanks again for your help with this.